# How to perform element-wise multiplication of two lists?

Tags: python, list, multiplication, elementwise-operations

I want to perform an element wise multiplication, to multiply two lists together by value in Python, like we can do it in Matlab.

This is how I would do it in Matlab.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
a .* b = [2, 6, 12, 20]
```

A list comprehension would give 16 list entries, for every combination `x * y` of `x` from `a` and `y` from `b`. Unsure of how to map this.

If anyone is interested why, I have a dataset, and want to multiply it by `Numpy.linspace(1.0, 0.5, num=len(dataset)) =)`.

Comment: Why are you asking this when you already now about numpy?

Comment: And by the way, this is element-wise multiplication, this is not a dot product.

Comment: Alternative: map(lambda x, y: x*y, list1, list2) #derp...

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Use a list comprehension mixed with `zip()`:.

```
[a*b for a,b in zip(lista,listb)]
```

Comment: On the other hand, if they want to do anything else beyond the trivial case here the OP would be well advised to use Numpy.

Comment: On Python 2 izip() could be a better choice.

Comment: You can also use `map(lambda x,y:x*y,lista,listb)`.

Comment: Just to add to what 'mbomb007' stated. To get this into a list form, you would need to use `list(map(lambda x ,y: x * y, lista, listb))`

Comment: Using pure python: Instead of using lambda, use the builtins: `itertools.starmap(operator.mul, zip(a, b))`

Answer (score 107):

Since you're already using `numpy`, it makes sense to store your data in a `numpy` array rather than a list. Once you do this, you get things like element-wise products for free:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [3]: b = np.array([2,3,4,5])

In [4]: a * b
Out[4]: array([ 2,  6, 12, 20])
```

Comment: Maybe not the most scientific, but I timed this against gahooa's answer using timeit. Numpy is actually slightly slower than the zip method.

Comment: In my case, where the lists contained binary values, the numpy solution was much faster than using the izip.

Answer (score 42):

Use np.multiply(a,b):

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
np.multiply(a,b)
```

Comment: The result is then an np.array [2 6 12 20], not a Python list [2, 6, 12, 20]. But you can write  np.multiply(a,b).tolist() if you need a Python list.

Answer (score 23):

You can try multiplying each element in a loop. The short hand for doing that is

```
ab = [a[i]*b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! code-only answers are generally discouraged - please add some explanation as to how this solves the questioner's question.

Answer (score 15):

Yet another answer:

`-1` ... requires import
`+1` ... is very readable

```
import operator
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [10,11,12,13]

list(map(operator.mul, a, b))
```

outputs [10, 22, 36, 52]

### Edit

For Python3.6+ map does not automatically unpack values.

Use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

```
import itertools
import operator

itertools.starmap(operator.mul, zip(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 12):

you can multiplication using `lambda`

```
foo=[1,2,3,4]
bar=[1,2,5,55]
l=map(lambda x,y:x*y,foo,bar)
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda x,y:x*y,foo,bar))` in Python 3

Answer (score 10):

Fairly intuitive way of doing this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]
ab = []                        #Create empty list
for i in range(0, len(a)):
     ab.append(a[i]*b[i])      #Adds each element to the list
```

Answer (score 6):

gahooa's answer is correct for the question as phrased in the heading, but if the lists are already numpy format ***or*** larger than ten it will be MUCH faster (3 orders of magnitude) as well as more readable, to do simple numpy multiplication as suggested by NPE. I get these timings:

```
0.0049ms -> N = 4, a = [i for i in range(N)], c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]
0.0075ms -> N = 4, a = [i for i in range(N)], c = a * b
0.0167ms -> N = 4, a = np.arange(N), c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]
0.0013ms -> N = 4, a = np.arange(N), c = a * b
0.0171ms -> N = 40, a = [i for i in range(N)], c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]
0.0095ms -> N = 40, a = [i for i in range(N)], c = a * b
0.1077ms -> N = 40, a = np.arange(N), c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]
0.0013ms -> N = 40, a = np.arange(N), c = a * b
0.1485ms -> N = 400, a = [i for i in range(N)], c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]
0.0397ms -> N = 400, a = [i for i in range(N)], c = a * b
1.0348ms -> N = 400, a = np.arange(N), c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]
0.0020ms -> N = 400, a = np.arange(N), c = a * b
```

i.e. from the following test program.

```
import timeit

init = ['''
import numpy as np
N = {}
a = {}
b = np.linspace(0.0, 0.5, len(a))
'''.format(i, j) for i in [4, 40, 400] 
                  for j in ['[i for i in range(N)]', 'np.arange(N)']]

func = ['''c = [a*b for a,b in zip(a, b)]''',
'''c = a * b''']

for i in init:
  for f in func:
    lines = i.split('\n')
    print('{:6.4f}ms -> {}, {}, {}'.format(
           timeit.timeit(f, setup=i, number=1000), lines[2], lines[3], f))
```

Answer (score 4):

For large lists, we can do it the iter-way:

```
product_iter_object = itertools.imap(operator.mul, [1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5])
```

`product_iter_object.next()` gives each of the element in the output list.

The output would be the length of the shorter of the two input lists.

Answer (score 4):

create an array of ones;
multiply each list times the array; 
convert array to a list

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [2,3,4,5]

c = (np.ones(len(a))*a*b).tolist()

[2.0, 6.0, 12.0, 20.0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Can use enumerate.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [2, 3, 4, 5]

ab = [val * b[i] for i, val in enumerate(a)]
```

Answer (score 4):

The `map` function can be very useful here.
Using `map` we can apply any function to each element of an iterable.

Python 3.x

```
>>> def my_mul(x,y):
...     return x*y
...
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [2,3,4,5]
>>>
>>> list(map(my_mul,a,b))
[2, 6, 12, 20]
>>>
```

Of course:

```
map(f, iterable)
```

is equivalent to

```
[f(x) for x in iterable]
```

So we can get our solution via:

```
>>> [my_mul(x,y) for x, y in zip(a,b)]
[2, 6, 12, 20]
>>>
```

In Python 2.x `map()` means: apply a function to each element of an iterable and construct a new list.
In Python 3.x, `map` construct iterators instead of lists.

Instead of `my_mul` we could use  `mul` operator

Python 2.7

```
>>>from operator import mul # import mul operator
>>>a = [1,2,3,4]
>>>b = [2,3,4,5]
>>>map(mul,a,b)
[2, 6, 12, 20]
>>>
```

Python 3.5+

```
>>> from operator import mul
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = [2,3,4,5]
>>> [*map(mul,a,b)]
[2, 6, 12, 20]
>>>
```

Please note that since `map()` constructs an iterator we use `*` iterable unpacking operator to get a list.
The unpacking approach is a bit faster then the `list` constructor:

```
>>> list(map(mul,a,b))
[2, 6, 12, 20]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

To maintain the list type, and do it in one line (after importing numpy as np, of course):

```
list(np.array([1,2,3,4]) * np.array([2,3,4,5]))
```

or

```
list(np.array(a) * np.array(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for lists of same length:

```
def lstsum(a, b):
    c = 0
    pos = 0
    for element in a:
        c += element * b[pos]
        pos += 1
    return c
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ast,sys

input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

list_1 = input_list[0]
list_2 = input_list[1]

import numpy as np

array_1 = np.array(list_1)
array_2 = np.array(list_2)
array_3 = array_1*array_2

print(list(array_3))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27925056)