# How calculate percentage error by comparing two lists for each list's element using Python

Tags: python, list, compare, percentage

I have two lists, for example:

```
a = [12, 0.2112, 0.2335, 4, 523, -0.55556, 0.212] # accepted value
b = [10, -0.0222, 0.5534, 4, 522, -0.99922, 0.877] # experimental value
```

I want to use this formula - 
`|accepted value(a[i]) - experimental value(b[i])| \ accepted value(a[i]) x 100%,` and get this result:

```
c = [16.66, 110.51, 137.00, 0.00, 0.191, 78.59, 313.67]
```

How is it possible to do this with the two lists without using **`numpy`**?

Comment: You can probably get unstuck by looking at the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function

Comment: If you mean that you want to iterate over `a` and `b` at the same time you can use the `zip` function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271484/how-to-perform-element-wise-multiplication-of-two-lists-in-python

Comment: btw, why is the 4th element in `c` is `100`? Shouldn't it be `0`? (Didn't check the rest)

Comment: `x 100%`? Noop.

Comment: George, I agree about the 4th element, I was in a hurry, thank you. But everything else is correct.

Comment: Yeah right "everything else is correct". Why does c have 11 values when a has 10 and b has 9?

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann, thank you too. I incorrectly used "," as a delimiter in numbers.Already fixed

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Sure. @wwii, I really sorry if I did something wrong. Thank you for instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with an ordinary loop

```
c = [abs(i-j)/i*100 for i,j in zip(a,b)]
print(c)
```

If you have zeros in `a`, then you can skip these (while keeping the same length) by including an if-else statement:

```
c = [abs(i-j)/i*100 if i != 0 else None for i,j in zip(a,b)]
print(c)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it List Comprehensions? I need to learn more... :)

Comment: @IluxaKuk it is indeed list comprehension.

Comment: If I will have zeros in data like this: a = [0,1,2,3,0,5], b= [2,5,8,0,4,7] ,I understand how to skip it:  c = abs(i-j)/i*100 for i,j in zip(a,b) if i !=0] but I get list like this  [400.0, 300.0, 100.0, 40.0], and can't save the same numbers of elements in output list,is it possible to do it? For example:    [ None, 400.0, 300.0, 100.0, None, 40.0]

Comment: @IluxaKuk I've editted my answer so it includes what you're asking.

Comment: Great! It interesting, when I use <is not> operator for float type I have: " ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero". But when I use !=, everything works perfectly.

Comment: @IluxaKuk thank you for pointing out this error, it should indeed be `!=`.