# Two lists in python. Check when the elements are of the same sign

Tags: python

I have two lists in python

```
list1=[1,3,5,-3,-3]
list2=[2,-3,3,-3,5]
```

I want to produce a list that is true when the elements are of the same sign

```
result=[True,False,True,True,False]
```

which is the fastest and more pythonic way to do this?

EDIT:

Solution

I solve it by transforming both list to numpy arrays

```
np.array(list1)*np.array(list1)>0
```

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you consider zero to be positive, negative or both?

Comment: Also, what is expected result when at least one of the elements is zero.

Comment: m m m that turns complicated. if 0 i would like that it produces false for any other number negative or positive

Answer (score 2):

The product of two numbers of the same sign should be positive, so you can do:

```
result = [a * b > 0 for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: "should be"? Are there some circumstances where that might not be the case? Also, if a pair of values are both zero this would give False so I suppose that depends on whether or not zero can be considered to be signed.

Comment: @Fred Well, floats can overflow and produce `inf`s.

Comment: mm yes i was thinking of that but this implies the use of for. isn't that slow ?

Comment: i wonder if this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10271498/4451521 is better?