# How to multiply the elements of two lists with each other in python?

Tags: python, list, nested-loops

You have to create an N-string.
An N-string is a string created using two lists. The first list consists of strings. The second list consists of integer
values. These two lists are of same length.
Each string from the first list has to be repeated for m-times where m is the respective integer value from the second
list. The resulting string is the concatenation of all these repeated strings.

```
def n_strings(names, numbers):
    nString = []
    for name in names:
        for number in numbers:
            n = name * number
            nString.append(n)
    return nString
names = ["Neymar","Abir","Samuel"]
numbers = [1,2,3]

print(n_strings(names,numbers))
```

Comment: What is your question? What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Comment: Yes, the idea is like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271484/how-to-perform-element-wise-multiplication-of-two-lists , but I cannot use zip().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the length of one array.

```
def n_strings(names, numbers):
    nString = ""
    for i in range(0,len(names)):
        n = names[i] * numbers[i]
        nString += n
    return nString
names = ["Neymar","Abir","Samuel"]
numbers = [1,2,3]

print(n_strings(names,numbers))
```